# Can an irreducible representation be unfaithful?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let's take the symmetric group S3, which multiplitation table is

[image]

I understand that its irreducible representation is the set of 2x2 matrices

[image]

But S3 has also an unfaithful representation where {e,d,f} goes to 1 and {a,b,c} goes to -1. Is this representation also irreducible? I think it isn't but I can't really argue why. Does Irreducible representations have to be faithful?

Comment: The constant $1$ map is irreducible.  That definitely isn't faithful. (except in the trivial case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Irreducible representations definitely don't have to be faithful.  Indeed, irreducible representations are representations that are as "small" as possible, which makes it *harder* for them to be faithful than general representations.  For instance, if $G$ is any group, there is a trivial $1$-dimensional representation of $G$ that sends every element of $G$ to $1$.  This is as far from faithful as possible, but is always irreducible.

More generally, any $1$-dimensional representation $V$ is irreducible: the only vector subspaces of $V$ are $0$ and $V$ itself, and so in particular there cannot be any subrepresentations of $V$ besides $0$ and $V$.  In particular, this applies to the $1$-dimensional representation of $S_3$ you are asking about.

Comment: Great Answer, thank you very much. I couldn't beleive that there was an irreducible rep smaller than the other irreducible rep I already knew, it sounded weird, haha.

Comment: On a tangent: Is there exactly one *faithful* irrep (not counting similarity transforms of same)? For S3 (in this example) that would be the 2x2 matrices.

Comment: @JobStancil: Well, $S_3$ happens to have only one faithful irrep, but a group can have more than one faithful irrep, or none at all.